# Tensorflow -> Syntaxnet -> как подключить модель русского языка и запускать разбор предложений на python?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow, естественный-язык

Не могу понять, как использовать сей инструмент для разбора предложений на русском языке.
Трудность вызывает подключение модели с русским языком. Я не понимаю, как это сделать.

С английским языком работает через запуск по команде:

```
"echo 'Bob brought the pizza to Alice.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh"
```

Вторая задача: запускать разбор предложений в скрипте на python (даешь на вход предложение, а на выходе получаешь разобранный Syntaxnet'ом вариант)